# can we find all topological properties?

Tags: general-topology

in general topology we define : [topological properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_property)

Now can we find all topological properties?

Comment: Whenever $\mathcal C$ is a class of topological spaces, being homeomorphic to a member of $\mathcal C$ is a topological property. So there are many

Comment: Short answer: we can't. The class of all topological properties is a proper class. There's no way for us to get a grip on all of them.

Answer (score 1):

All topology investigates topological properties. You can taste their flavor in books of general topology. For instance, I may recommend to you "[General Topology](https://mega.co.nz/#!odRXmbAJ!HIdtDZAkelt_NLTi3Uq6PBm5WCvlgkbv1yjnGUax1Pc)" by Ryszard Engelking.
A topologist usually considers only properties relevant to a topic which he researches.